# Order by closest date, future and past separately limited to 5 rows each using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table called Event in my postgresql database. The table includes a datetime column called time. I want to get (separately) 5 events from the past that are the closest to present date and 5 events that will take place in the nearest future. Is there a way to do that without querying for all events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a more efficient way, but you can `UNION` the past and future events with a Query like:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

past = Event.query.filter(Event.time <= func.now()).order_by(Event.time.desc()).limit(5)
future = Event.query.filter(Event.time >= func.now()).order_by(Event.time).limit(5)

past.union(future)
```